# use of "as much as"

Tags: as

I come up with a question pretty confusing.

I'd like to make a sentence but somebody Keep saying it is wrong. I want you to check if it is right.

The sentence is :

> He would play the guitar more skillfully as much as she used to play her piano.

I will make the sentence mean that she used to play the piano with great perfomance for 10hours and he was able to Play the guitar keeping great performance for 2hours but now he has made progress with his ability and he is guessed to Play the guitar greatly for 10 hours.

Does the sentence aree to my Explanation?
if I'm having wrong sense, please Point it out.

Cf) Could you bring up any adjective suit to explain great performance instead of skillful

Comment: He could play the guitar as well as she could play the piano. He had as much skill on the guitar as she had on the piano. His virtuosity on the guitar was as great as hers on the piano. He was as adept on the guitar as she was on the piano. He was as great a guitarist as she a pianist.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "10 hours".   Do you mean "years"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the context and the tense, the following sentences are possible:

Now he plays the guitar as much/long as she plays the piano.

Now he plays the guitar as long/much as she used to play the piano.

Now he plays the guitar as skillfully and as much/long as she plays the piano.

He would play the guitar as skillfully and as long/much as she would play the piano.

Comment: thank you for your anwer! but didn't you leave 'as' out in front of 'she' in the final sentence? and can I use 'as' several times like that?

Comment: @JBL, you are right. I have edited the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got the meaning of the sentence as you intended, but you could try this:

> He would play the guitar as skillfully as she played her piano.

Let's assume '*he*' to be **Sam** and *'she'* to be **Lily**. Then the meaning of the above sentence would be:

"*Lily gave a wonderful performance when she played the piano. Sam, who is playing the guitar now, would give a similarly unforgettable performance.*"

Now, if you wanted to say that Sam would give a better performance playing his guitar, when compared to Lily piano recital, then you could say:

> He would play the guitar more skillfully than she played her piano.

**Note**: I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but this is based on what I understood from your post.